# Blazor(ise) DataGrid iterate through DataGridColumns in code (behind)

Tags: datagrid, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0, blazorise

Sorry if this is a Blazorise and not just a general Blazor WebAseembly question, being a noob in both I'm just not sure so posting with both tags, but I'd like to display a list of items in a DataGrid that has certain columns sortable (multiple simultaneously and not by just one at a time), and once that sortable columns desc/asc/none direction setting occurs I'd like to be able to read their set direction properties state on a button click to pass it along to another component...only I can't do it with a @ref like this:

```
<DataGrid TItem="Item"
          Data="@ItemList"
          @ref="dataGrid"
          @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedItem"
          Responsive ShowPager="true" PageSize="10">
        <DataGridCommandColumn TItem="Item" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="Item" Field="@nameof(Item.Id)" Caption="#" Sortable="false" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="Item" Field="@nameof(Item.SKU)" Caption="SKU" Sortable="false"/>
        <DataGridColumn TItem="Item" Field="@nameof(Item.ModelId)" Caption="Model" Sortable="false" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="Item" Field="@nameof(Item.Year)" Caption="Year" Editable="true" Direction="SortDirection.Ascending" />
        <DataGridColumn TItem="Item" Field="@nameof(Item.Weight)" Caption="Weight" Editable="true" Direction="SortDirection.Ascending" />
</DataGrid>

@code {
    private Blazorise.DataGrid.DataGrid<Ad> dataGrid;
    protected void OnClick(MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string sortdirections="";
        dataGrid.DataGridColumns.
        foreach(Blazorise.DataGrid.DataGridColumn<Ad> col in dataGrid.DataGridColumns)
        {
            if (col.Sortable)
            {
                i++;
                switch(col.SortDirection){
                  case SortDirection.Ascending: smartsort += ("a" + i.ToString()); break;
                  case SortDirection.Descending: smartsort += ("d" + i.ToString()); break;
                  case SortDirection.None: break;
                }
            }
        }
        . . .
    }
```

Because I get a build error

> CS1579    foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type
> 'RenderFragment' because 'RenderFragment' does not contain a public
> instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'

given that the dataGrid.DataGridColumns seemingly doesn't reference the actual rendered instance of the dataGrid component I'm using (but a RenderFragment instead), because one should probably databind variables to those Direction properties I guess...but the trouble with me databinding Direction properties to some or particular variable(s) is that I'd like to make the DataGrid a bit more dynamic in the future, in which case I wouldn't even know in advance during design-time what and which columns would be sortable and the user could be setting some sortable columns to sort direction none...thus I need some (pardon the pun) direction please on how to do it this way (basically like using old ASP.NET server-side components to access its run-time state in a blazor webassembly app) or how to do it with preferably just a single databound variable dynamically but so that just a few columns out of the ones displayed are going to actually be sortable through a click on a datagrid column name with which the user could change the sort order direction (so that the databound variable then after the user finishes clicking the sort orders of colums holds the state of that datagrid indicating which of the sortable columns have been set to ascend and which of the to descend, if any of them, since they can also choose direction none)?

TIA

Comment: Whilst writing this I came to the idea that I should probably be making my own DataGrid component that would on a change of direction on each sortable column be updating property `sortdirections` that button connected to `OnClick` does, but I'm not sure it'd be easy enough to make a component that was as capable as the Blazorise's DataGrid component...but if that's not a too big of an issue to make on my own I'd appreciate any insight into that as well...it's just that I wouldn't know where to start now and using an already pre-built and quite capable component seems like a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Blazorise has a sort mode:

```
<DataGrid ... Sortable="true" SortMode="DataGridSortMode.Multiple" ...
```

https://blazorise.com/docs/helpers/enums/datagrid

If that's not exactly what you are looking for, ask [Mladen on gitter](https://gitter.im/stsrki/Blazorise) or check out the source code [here](https://github.com/Megabit/Blazorise).

Comment: It is what I'm looking for exactly (in terms of UI), which is why I chose it, but trouble is that I'd like then afterwards to know (in this case on another button click) what is the current set SortDirection of all Sortable DataGridColumns along with their indexes among sortable columns (which is something I haven't found or just don't see in the datagrid component in question)...the above code doesn't work to read their current states, and it might be that I'm just doing it badly (or should have a cast maybe?)...but I'll try gitter also thank you.

Comment: Think I may have found also another approach through reflection but can't figure out what to do next after accessing PropertyInfo[] props = dataGrid.GetType().GetProperties(); ... I can iterate foreach (var prop in props) in there but this seems to be working with magic string names which I'm not sure which I should supply to figure out which of the columns were sortable and what if any sortdirection was set up/down and not none.